# Toggle navigation button not displaying menu, about and awards when reducing the size of the web-page to below 768px breakpoint

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <title>David Chu's China Bistro'</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oxygen:wght@ S300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <!--here container is used and not container-fluid because there is little info on this homepage thus we don't want the width to stretch to the full width of the screen-->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a href="index.html" class="pull-left visible-md visible-lg">
                        <div id="logo-img" alt="Logo image"></div><!--the id #logo-img is responsible to print the logo-->
                    </a>
                    <div class="navbar-brand">
                        <a href="index.html"><h1>David Chu's China Bistro</h1></a>
                        <p>
                            <img src="images/K-star-logo.jpg" id="K-logo" alt="Kosher certification" />
                            <span>Kosher certified</span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div id="collapsable-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <!--used to display our menu items(use unordered list)-->
                        <li>
                            <a href="menu-categories.html">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery"<!--glyphicon is used to import the image of the cutlery and let it behave as a font--></span><br class="hidden-xs" /><!--break tag is used here to remove the Menu word when we reach the breakpoint-->Menu
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span><br class="hidden-xs" />About
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate"></span>
                                <br class="hidden-xs" />Awards
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="phone" class="hidden-xs">
                            <a href="tel:410-602-5008">
                                <span>410-602-5008</span>
                            </a><div>*We Deliver</div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My code is responsible for displaying the navbar of a website. When my screen is at full-page i am getting next to the restaurant's name  "menu", "awards" and "About".

When the page is squeezed (or website used on a phone), I need the "menu", "awards" and "About" buttons to disappear and display in their place a toggle navigation button that when clicked will display those 3 buttons, which is not happening.